# How to identify a zip compressed file in a Oracle-Database with Java

Tags: java, oracle11g, zip, blob

How to identify if a Resultset entry is a BLOB or a zipped BLOB?
If the BLOB is zipped i need to unzip it.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatemant("select BLOB from X");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
         Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
         if(isZippedBlob(blob)){
             Blob unzipBlob = unzipBlob(blob);
         }
     }
}
```

I would appreciate a implemented version of

```
boolean isZippedBlob(Blob)
```

or any kind of algorithm i can identify a zipped BLOB and a BLOB.

Comment: Zip files have a zip file header. You (or a library) can examine the first bytes to see if it has a zip header or not.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the advise. I use rs.getBlob(1).getBytes(1, (int) rs.getBlob(1).lengt()); but the values i get dont fit with this specific header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the Bytes from the BLOB

```
    byte[] bArr = rs.getBlob(1).getBytes(1, (int) rs.getBlob(1).length());
```

and i received 31, -117, 8.
the magic number of a .zip is 50 4B 03 04 = 80 75 03 04 in decimal
so i got curious and indeed it was not a zip file it was a gzip instead and that starts with 1F 8B 08 -> 31 139 08 in dec. So all i need to do is to compare the first 3 bytes with 31 139(256-117) 8.